# how to start remote process group from Nifi UI?

Tags: apache-nifi

Hy,

I looked for an information and did not find it in documentation or on the web : how to start/stop remote process group for Nifi UI ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on it -> Enable Transmission

Comment: So if there are 27 remote process groups , i have to click on each one ?

Comment: unfortunaly, i guess. you can go in summary -> Remote Process Groups to see theirs status and go to theirs location.

Comment: If you have 22, then automating with the rest API would be the best option